# Validation of Android login using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql

```
public class SecondActivity extends Base2_Activity
{
Button back;
Button login2;
EditText uname,password;
boolean pass;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.secondctivity);
uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.uname1);
password= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password1);


login2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.login2);
login2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
new PostDataAsyncTask().execute();
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
});

}

public class PostDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
String resresult=null;
try {

resresult = postText();

} catch (NullPointerException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

return resresult;
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(result),   
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//int res= Integer.parseInt(result);

if(result=="error"){

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
else
{
GlobalVar.number= result;

System.out.println(GlobalVar.number);
Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),  Welcome.class);
startActivity(i);
}
}


}


private String postText(){

String responseStr=null;
try{

String postReceiverUrl = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/a/login.php";

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postReceiverUrl);

MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

entityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);


entityBuilder.addTextBody("uname", uname.getText().toString());
entityBuilder.addTextBody("password", password.getText().toString());



HttpEntity entity = entityBuilder.build();
post.setEntity(entity);

HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);       


HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

if (resEntity != null) {

responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();


}




} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}


return responseStr;
}
}
```

Here is my php code

```
<?php
$err;
$uname= $_POST['uname'];
$password= $_POST['password'];
$db = 'eventalert';  
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("not connected");  
mysql_select_db($db, $conn) or die("could not find database");  
$query= mysql_query("SELECT registration_id FROM user WHERE  uname='$uname' 
AND password='$password'");
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());  
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $rows;
if($rows == 0) { 
echo "No Such User Found"; 
}
else  {
echo "User Found"; 
}

?>
```

While login I want to check whether user have put valid username and password or not. It should match with the database in the back end. However it's not working. It's showing error. Can you tell my the right way to code it?

Comment: what exact error are you getting? and also when comparing objects, use equals not ==, unless if your comparing numerals such as integer. so instead of   if(result=="error"), replace it with if (result.equals("error"))

Comment: what does the echo show ?

Comment: add this Log.i("response",resresult) in the end of doinbackground before the return resresult

Comment: Its saying undefined variable of username and password

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps-

1. While login with android app, send json of username and password to server.
2. On server side, parse json and match credentials in your database, if they exists, send a text of json back to android app like 
   {"status":"success"}
3. If they doesn't exists, send different text in json like-
   {"status":"failure"}
4. Now check json from mobile side that if "success" values comes in json or not. It yes, login from app otherwise not.